# apache rewrite mod-blocking url with a particular context root

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We blocked following PUMA rest url (via httpd.conf file on IHS servers)/contenthandler /xyz/data/users/profiles

but we are still getting hit by PUMA rest urls that don't match the exact text as above but are variations of the above uri.

how can we devise a rule on IHS that blocks all requests that contain PUMA context:*/xyz/data/* ?

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    /contenthandler/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    /xyz/data/users/profiles
    RewriteRule .* - [F]*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `[OR]` your conditions otherwise the rule would never match.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contenthandler(/.*)? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xyz/data(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above conditions check for a PUMA context **prefix** and forbids the request if it matches.